# Python - ValueError: invalid literal for float():

Tags: python, linux, csv, numpy

I've a csv file and I am trying to calculate the average of each of the columns present in it.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

with open('/home/rnish/Desktop/lbm-reference.dat.ref-2013-01-30-13-00-15big.csv', "rU") as f:
    columns = f.readline().strip().split(' ')
    numRows = 0
    sums = [0] * len(columns)

    for line in f:
        values = line.split(" ")
        print values
        for i in xrange(len(values)):
           sums[i] += float(values[i])
        numRows += 1

#    for index, summedRowValue in enumerate(sums):
#        print columns[index], 1.0 * summedRowValue / numRows
```

The error I get is:

```
  File "excel.py", line 15, in <module>
    sums[i] += float(values[i])
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 0,536880742,8861743,0,4184866,4448905
```

This is how the output from `print values` is:

```
['0,256352728,10070198,5079543,5024472,34764\n']
['0,352618127,10102320,4987654,3082111,1902909\n']
['0,505838297,9977968,423278,4709666,5041639\n']
['0,506598469,10083489,0,5032146,5054715\n']
['0,536869414,7229488,39934,4322290,3607046\n']
```

This is how the csv file looks:

```
0,256641418,10669052,4803710,4759922,0
0,484517531,9889830,1457230,4084777,4959529
0,506902273,9673699,0,5281012,5293376
```

Could some one shed some light and help me understand this issue:

I am assuming after reading a couple of posts that it is due to the new line character. am I correct?

Answer (score 3):

You are splitting a .cvs file at a space - but there are no spaces in your string. Try splitting at the comma instead:

```
    columns = f.readline().strip().split(',')
```

Comment: `columns = f.readline().strip().split(',')`
`numRows = 0`
`sums = [0] * len(columns)`

this is how it looks atm. but it doesn't work.

Comment: Just realized - you also need to split the line at commas in the `        values = line.split(" ")` line... change it to `        values = line.split(",")`. Is that better?

Comment: Thanks!. I did not catch that.

Comment: It ignores the first line of the csv file. I don't know why.

Comment: It ignores the first line because you're explicitly reading the first line (to get the `columns` list), but then not using it again. Try replacing the code initializing `sums` with `sums = columns` and you should be set.

Answer (score 1):

Using [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.loadtxt("data.csv", delimiter=",")
mean = np.mean(a, axis=0)
print(mean)
```

Using [csv module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html):

```
import csv
import sys

it = csv.reader(sys.stdin, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
avg = next(it, [])
count = 1
for count, row in enumerate(it, start=2):
     for i, value in enumerate(row):
          avg[i] += value
avg = [a/count for a in avg]
print(avg)
```

#### [Output](http://ideone.com/CKe9k0)

```
[0.0, 431655407.0, 9492692.6, 2106081.8, 4434137.0, 3128214.6]
```

Comment: mean = np.mean(a, axis=0)

It gives out values in `[  0.00000000e+00   5.49352277e+08   1.06912389e+07   7.33264049e+06
   6.79808023e+06   6.80590208e+06]`. that's an overhead for converting into floating point values

Comment: @rnish: check your input data. I've got: `[0.00000000e+00   4.31655407e+08   9.49269260e+06   2.10608180e+06   4.43413700e+06   3.12821460e+06]` that coincides exactly with the csv results.

Comment: I need to check for a way to convert ndarray data from scientific notation to floating point. :-). The data that I gave was just a small part of the csv file

Comment: @rnish: the data is the same. You can print it however you like. To save an array in the csv format: `np.savetxt(sys.stdout, (mean,), fmt="%.1f", delimiter=", ")` You could use a filename or any file object instead of `sys.stdout.